# How to track keywords from searches using UTM Tags

Tags: php, html, google-ads-api

I am trying to track the keywords that lead to my site using UTM tags so I know which ads are generating traffic.  Is it possible to so? And if so, how do I get the keywords from the search engine?

This is the code I have for capturing the keyword but for some reason the keyword does appear in the url or in the form that gets submitted by the user.

```
var SearchKeyword = (location.search.split('SearchKeyword=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
  if ( (SearchKeyword && !term) || (SearchKeyword && term == "") ) {
    $("#Field126").attr("value", term);
  }
```

Comment: I would have used `document.referrer`, but Google change of location before opening the link so we always get : http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean tracking those keywords in **Google Analytics** as you mention UTM tags.

The easiest way would be to [link your Analytics and Adwords accounts](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341). This will give you the most fine-grained Adwords data within your Analytics account.

If that's not possible, you can use a [tracking template](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447) in your Adwords account containing `{lpurl}?utm_term={keyword}`. This will insert the triggering keyword for every ad click into the `utm_term` parameter, where it can be picked up by Google Analytics.

Comment: I updatd the question with the code that should capture the keywords on the page itself but does not work.  Can you explain why?

Comment: It seems you are looking for a query parameter called "SearchKeyword" in the code snippet, but at the same time you mention UTM parameters which are used for Analytics, so I'm not sure what it exactly is that you are trying to do.